# flutter context become null if list is not empty

Tags: flutter, dart, nullpointerexception, null, flutter-provider

I have a form to create/update activity which is a stateful widget like this:

```dart
class ActivityForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Activity activity;
  final bool isEdit;

  const ActivityForm({Key key, this.activity, this.isEdit}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ActivityFormState createState() => _ActivityFormState();
}

class _ActivityFormState extends State<ActivityForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<int> activityDetailIdToBeDeleted;

  ...
  void submitHandler() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    // Mapping input field to activity model
    Activity activity = Activity(
        id: widget.activity.id,
        tanggal: _tanggalController.text,
        uraianKegiatan: _uraianKegiatanController.text,
        pic: _picController.text,
        jumlahTim: int.parse(_jumlahTimController.text),
        kendala: _kendalaController.text,
        penyelesaian: _penyelesaianController.text,
        approverUserId: selectedApprovalUser,
        rincianPekerjaan: rincianPekerjaanList,
        status: 'PENDING');

    if (widget.isEdit) {
      await Provider.of<ActivityProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateActivity(activity, activityDetailIdToBeDeleted);
    } else {
      await Provider.of<ActivityProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .createActivity(activity);
    }

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

in my form there are some detail list of activities. When i press delete it adds the id of
the activity detail to the list of "to be deleted" :

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
  onPressed: () => removeRincianPekerjaan(
  activityDetail.description),),
```

here's the function:

```dart
void removeRincianPekerjaan(desc) {
    if (widget.isEdit) {
      int detailId = rincianPekerjaanList
          .where((element) => element.description == desc)
          .first
          .id;
      if (!activityDetailIdToBeDeleted.contains(detailId))
        activityDetailIdToBeDeleted.add(detailId);
      print(activityDetailIdToBeDeleted);
    }

    setState(() {
      rincianPekerjaanList
          .removeWhere((element) => element.description == desc);
    });
  }
```

that list of ids will be sent to provider which looks like this:

```dart
Future<bool> updateActivity(
      Activity activity, List<int> activityDetailToBeDeleted) async {
    final response = await ActivityService()
        .updateActivity(activity.id.toString(), activity.toMap());

    if (response != null) {
      // Update Success.
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = json.decode(response.body);
        removeActivityToList(activity);
        activity = Activity.fromMap(body['activity']);
        addActivityToList(activity);

        if (activityDetailToBeDeleted.isNotEmpty) {
          print("to be deleted is not empty.");
          print("ID to be deleted: ${activityDetailToBeDeleted.join(",")}");
          final res = await ActivityService()
              .deleteActivityDetail(activityDetailToBeDeleted.join(","));
          if (res.statusCode == 204) {
            print('ID DELETED.');
            return true;
          }
        }

        return true;
      }
      // Error unauthorized / token expired
      else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        var reauth = await AuthProvider().refreshToken();

        if (reauth) {
          return await createActivity(activity);
        } else {
          return Future.error('unauthorized');
        }
      }

      return Future.error('server error');
    }

    return Future.error('connection failed');
  }
```

the problem is if the list is empty, or i didn't add the id to the list, builder context is not null but if i add an id to the list "to be deleted", the `Navigator.pop(context)` will throw an error because `context` is null. I don't understand why it becomes null.

[full code in here](https://gist.github.com/askareija/c24efa0fe33108df336d282cf29c5367)

Comment: activityDetailIdToBeDeleted is not initialize. The problem may be caused by this.

Comment: @bcihan i've initialized it in `initState()` method, `activityDetailIdToBeDeleted = [];`.it's still thrown error `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.` caused by context being null.

Comment: Ok, I think I solved this time. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your [context] must came from the build() method. Like this.

```
void submitHandler(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    // Mapping input field to activity model
    Activity activity = Activity(
        id: widget.activity.id,
        tanggal: _tanggalController.text,
        uraianKegiatan: _uraianKegiatanController.text,
        pic: _picController.text,
        jumlahTim: int.parse(_jumlahTimController.text),
        kendala: _kendalaController.text,
        penyelesaian: _penyelesaianController.text,
        approverUserId: selectedApprovalUser,
        rincianPekerjaan: rincianPekerjaanList,
        status: 'PENDING');

    if (widget.isEdit) {
      await Provider.of<ActivityProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateActivity(activity, activityDetailIdToBeDeleted);
    } else {
      await Provider.of<ActivityProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .createActivity(activity);
    }
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }
```

Comment: now the error is different, `FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.`

Comment: hmm, i guess it's because routing issue. can you check the route before pop method?

Comment: i guess there's nothing wrong with the routing, start from home screen i press edit which the code is `Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(...))` then button with submitHandler above. weirdly, if i commented deleteActivityDetail service from the activity provider it's working as expected, even without passing the `BuildContext context`. (this activity provider contains 2 services, 1 to update activity, 1 to delete activity detail if list of ids is not empty). 

you can check full code here: https://gist.github.com/askareija/c24efa0fe33108df336d282cf29c5367

Comment: Lets wrap Navigator with SchedulerBinding for rendering. I made some changes in my answer.

Comment: It's still give an error, but i have resolved it. the problem was async/await, it didn't await for 2nd service that calling api to destroy list of ids to be deleted. thank you for your help btw.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, finally :)